# Nginx redirecting to example.com/*

Tags: nginx, ssl

My nginx configuration has two redirect rules:

1. HTTP to HTTPS

   ```
   if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
   }
   ```
2. WWW to non-WWW

   ```
   server_name  www.alphainvesting.co.il;
   return   301 https://alphainvesting.co.il$request_uri;
   ```

Everything works great, except when users go to http://www.alphainvesting.co.il. Then they are being redirected to https://alphainvesting.co.il/* (which returns a 404 error of course).

Worth mentioning that I'm using Cloudflare, but I do not have page rules.

Comment: Don't use `if` for `http` forwarding. Use a separate `server` block for HTTP.

Comment: I'd look at CloudFlare for this, try looking at the logs of the original request to see if it is indeed NGINX that's adding the * or if it is part of the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$uri` instead of `$request_uri` for removing the www

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help.